# Cannt seed data in EF5 code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I use EF5 in a MVC4 Project. my problem is i can't get seeding data to work. and i searched before post this question but i couldn't figure it out.so please guid me. thanks

here is my DbContext class:

```
public class AminBarEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CarType> CarTypes { get; set; }
}

public class AminBarEntitiesInitializer :DropCreateDatabaseAlways<AminBarEntities>
{
    protected override void Seed(AminBarEntities dbContext)
    {
        // seed data
        dbContext.Branches.Add(new Branch() { BranchName = "قزوین" });
        dbContext.Branches.Add(new Branch() { BranchName = "البرز" });

        dbContext.CarTypes.Add(new CarType() { CarTypeName = "موتور" });
        dbContext.CarTypes.Add(new CarType() { CarTypeName = "وانت" });
        dbContext.CarTypes.Add(new CarType() { CarTypeName = "نیسان" });
        dbContext.CarTypes.Add(new CarType() { CarTypeName = "مزدا" });
        dbContext.CarTypes.Add(new CarType() { CarTypeName = "مینی خاور" });
        dbContext.CarTypes.Add(new CarType() { CarTypeName = "خاور 4 متری" });
        dbContext.CarTypes.Add(new CarType() { CarTypeName = "خاور 6 متری" });
  //  dbContext.SaveChanges();

    //    base.Seed(dbContext);

    }
}
```

and i've puted this code in global.asax

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new AminBar.Models.AminBarEntitiesInitializer());
```

but no success.

Comment: what doesn't work with this code? does it error? why is your `SaveChanges()` commented out? "no success" doesn't explain what your question is.

Comment: I put a breakpoint but it doesn't raise this initializer at all i think. it does't throw any error. and no success means it doesn't seed the data into my database. so my question is where i'm doing wrong?

Comment: why the `dbContext.SaveChanges();` is commented?

Comment: it wasn't commented before, i read somewhere there is no need for that line of code!! anyway it wasn't working when it wasn't commented out.